# why google ignore my links page?

Tags: google

I have a website, where I'm loading all the data via AJAX.
Since Google doesn't work with AJAX and the ways to make it AJAX-friendly are a bit odd, I thought that by creating a links page, where it links, from server side, to all the links that I'm loading in AJAX - will solve the problem.
But unfortunately, that doesn't seem to work. Google Webmaster Tools shows that even though my links page discovered, the content of it - the links - are totally ignored.

I can only assume that google tend to ignore links in such pages.

my question is - WHY?! and furthermore, how to overcome this.

Comment: You made a big mistake by using ajax to power your website. You're attempting to use a hack to work around it. You can't expect good results. You can only hope for it.

Comment: Have you seen Google's guidelines on the subject? This blog post is a bit old, but might be a good place to start: http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2007/11/spiders-view-of-web-20.html

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring is not the right term. If your page is linked, Googlebot will see it eventually. What it is most likely doing is not giving it importance because it has no valuable content.

What you need to do is submit all your links as a sitemap using Google Webmaster Tools. Google accepts both text and XML sites maps. [Here is the information from Google](http://support.google.com/sites/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=100283). This way, Google knows this is an index of your pages and not simply another *links page*.

With a generic page that has a large number of links, the value those links give to other pages is pretty much nothing because the incoming importance is divided among so many pages.

Comment: Sitemap is never enough for this case.

Answer (score 0):

Google can parse Javascript but when and why they do I don't know. Have you viewed your site as Googlebot, from Webmaster Tools (Fetch as Googlebot). Your links are loading server side after the page has loaded? Why not generate a static page of links instead of using AJAX?